# Execution failed for task ':generateMetadataFileForIosArm64Publication'

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am reading this [Creating your first Kotlin Multiplatform library](https://dev.to/kotlin/how-to-build-and-publish-a-kotlin-multiplatform-library-creating-your-first-library-1bp8). I updated the [maven-publish Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html). After that I run the command `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`.

I am getting error

```
Execution failed for task ':generateMetadataFileForIosArm64Publication'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/vmodi/IdeaProjects/AndroidModule/build/classes/kotlin/iosArm64/main/klib/AndroidModule.klib (No such file or directory)
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.20"
    id("maven-publish")
}

group = "me.vmodcleari"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        withJava()
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
    ios()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting
        val jvmTest by getting
        val iosMain by getting
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}
```

Comment: What OS do you use? Do you have any files in your iosMain folder?

Comment: I use mac os and I don't have any file

Comment: Can you please try to add a .kt file with dummy code and try again?

Comment: Yeah its work without any error. Thank you so much

Comment: This is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52344/Unclear-error-for-task-generateMetadataFileForIosArm64Publicatio